# Error code 2 when trying to install pip in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, subprocess, pip, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use an AWS Lambda function to start other Lambda functions, and some of the functions require non-standard python libraries. I thought a good solution would be to have the first Lambda function install pip, then use it to install the modules, then fire up the secondary Lambda functions. I download the basic get-pip.py from a s3 bucket, and then try to install it.

```
print(subprocess.check_output(['python', '/tmp/lambdaTools/get-pip.py']))
```

Runs for about 30 seconds, leading me to believe it begins executing properly, and then gives the error:

```
START RequestId: 5a6b8511-c05f-11e5-9e41-c1b36be05f9c Version: $LATEST
Command '['python', '/tmp/lambdaTools/get-pip.py']' returned non-zero exit status 2: CalledProcessError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambdaTools.py", line 34, in lambdaTools_handler
    return operations[operation](event)
  File "/var/task/lambdaTools.py", line 27, in <lambda>
    'create': lambda x: create_function(x.get('function_name'), x.get('bucket_path') ),
  File "/var/task/lambdaTools.py", line 62, in create_function
    print(subprocess.check_output(['python',local_path+get_pip]))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['python', '/tmp/lambdaTools/get-pip.py']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

It doesn't seem to give me any other information other than it failed with error code 2.

Comment: I haven't really looked at ``get-pip.py`` but I suspect it may be trying to install some stuff into system libraries that are not writable by the Lambda function.

Comment: That's kind of what I suspected, any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Why are you installing pip? AWS Lambda Python version is 2.7 which comes with pip.

Comment: Really? When I try calling pip from subprocess.check_output it gives OSError 2 'No such file or directory'

Comment: You should bundle your dependencies before pushing your lambda code up.  `pip install -r requirements.txt -t path/to/your/lambda_code` will do this. Of course if any of your dependencies have compiled code in them, things are going to get a bit more complicated.

Comment: I know bundling is the supported way, but it is not always ideal because it adds complexity to the deployment process and makes the console almost useless.

Answer (score 0):

> some of the functions require non-standard python libraries.

What non-standard libraries are you referring to? If you want to use libraries that are not provided as default by the AWS Lambda python environment then the recommended approach is to package those libraries with your lambda function. See: [Deploying Lambda with other python packages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

> then fire up the secondary Lambda functions.

Even if you invoke other lambdas it is not guaranteed that the new lambdas will be invoked in the same container/instance/machine as the current one. See this [AWS Lambda - container reuse](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/)

Answer (score 0):

Once a Lambda function reaches it's max size of 50MB it will crash and exit without providing any useful information. I would highly recommend you install any dependancies and package these within your zip prior to upload and consider S3 for storage.